# Check DBNull in C#

Tags: c#, dbnull

I have a StronglyTyped data Row object and I can access it like this.

```
accountFilter.Currency_ID
```

Currency_ID (Type of Int) is the row name. AccountFilter is the DataRow.
When it gives a value, no problem. But when the column value is NULL, it gives a DBNull Exception. I want to check the value for DBNull but it doesn't work.

```
bool a = Convert.IsDBNull(accountFilter.Currency_ID.ToString()); //doesnt work
```

Non of [these](http://forums.asp.net/t/1383849.aspx/1) examples dont work.

Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What if you remove the `.ToString()`?

Comment: @RichardEv By "doesn't work" hey says, "it gives a DBNull Exception".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, a row in a table of a typed data set has a `IsXYZNull()` method for every nullable column. Have you tried

```
bool a = accountFilter.IsCurrency_IDNull();
```

This, however, only works if `accountFilter` is not of type `DataRow` but of the *specialized data row type from your typed data set*.

For example: If you have a typed data set which contains a table named `Test`, there would be a specialized table class `TestTable` and a specialized data row class named `TestTableRow`. If the `Test` table contained a nullable field `TestField`, the `TestTableRow` class would contain a method `IsTestFieldNull()`, so you could call

```
bool isnull = testTable[0].IsTestFieldNull();
```

to determine whether the `TestField` field in the first row of the `TestTable testTable` was `null`.

Note that the following does not work, as the result is not of type `TestTableRow` but of type `DataRow`, so you'd have to cast this to `TestTableRow`:

```
bool isnull = testTable.Rows[0].IsTestFieldNull(); // Won't compile
bool isnull = ((TestTableRow)testTable.Rows[0]).IsTestFieldNull(); // Will compile because of cast
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check it from this?

```
accountFilter.Fields["Currency_ID"]
```